# Posting a JSON Object to a web method - $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get data from a form on a button click and send it to a web method in my code behind.  I'd like to pass it as a JSON object or at least I think that's the convention?  Here's my current code however it generates an error (Shown below the code).

```
$("#addTask")
    .click(function( event ) {
    var newTask = new Object();
        newTask.TaskName = $('#ctl00_ContentArea_taskName').val();
        newTask.TaskDescription = $('#ctl00_ContentArea_taskDescription').val();
        newTask.SQLObjectID = $('#ctl00_ContentArea_sqlReportingID').val();
        newTask.WarehouseSQLObjectID = $('#ctl00_ContentArea_warehouseSQLObjectID').val();

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'AddTask.aspx/validateTask',
           data: JSON.stringify(newTask),
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           async: false,
           success : function(data) { 
                alert( data.d ); 
           }
        });  
    });
```

__

```
{"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027newTask\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

I've tried having my web method in a bunch of different ways, such as but not limited to:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function validateTask(ByVal newTask As TaskBO)
```

Or with a bunch of individual parameters as strings.

What is the correct way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?  What do I not understand about formatting JSON objects?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you want: `data: { newTask: newTask },` and remove the `contentType` option. Although it might be: `data: JSON.stringify({ newTask: newTask }), contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: If he doesn't use `stringify` it will use URL-encoding instead of JSON encoding. Although it's likely that's what the webservice expects.

Comment: @Barmar Ahh I see. I edited my comment; does my second suggestion make sense?

Comment: Some day I'm going to ask a question that's difficult and can't be answered in 5 minutes...  
@Ian, the 2nd part of your answer worked, post it as the actual answer and I'll select it.  Thanks!

Comment: @Greg Haha well it wasn't an easy question, it was just something I happened to notice. And it doesn't matter the difficulty; you need the help, we try to do that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web service expects an item with the key "newTask" (as shown by your method's parameter). Your request will be sent as:

```
{
    "TaskName": "stuff",
    "TaskDescription": "stuff",
    "SQLObjectID": "stuff",
    "WarehouseSQLObjectID": "stuff"
}
```

But you really need it to be:

```
{
    "newTask": {
        "TaskName": "stuff",
        "TaskDescription": "stuff",
        "SQLObjectID": "stuff",
        "WarehouseSQLObjectID": "stuff"
    }
}
```

So change your `$.ajax()` call to be:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    newTask: newTask
}),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using a separate js file for this code to work, **verify the client ids**
- If there are more properties on the class for the *newTask*, you can always exclude unnecessary properties from json object using **delete** operator.( for example: delete newTask.UnnecessaryProperty)